# "Not sending request to CloudTrace: no traces or project_id is empty" logs in ESP

Tags: gcloud

I'm using gcloud ESP proxy, and I've got these logs happening every second:

```
2020/03/17 02:47:38[debug]9#9: Not sending request to CloudTrace: no traces or project_id is empty.
2020/03/17 02:47:39[debug]9#9: Not sending request to CloudTrace: no traces or project_id is empty.
2020/03/17 02:47:40[debug]9#9: Not sending request to CloudTrace: no traces or project_id is empty.
2020/03/17 02:47:41[debug]9#9: Not sending request to CloudTrace: no traces or project_id is empty.
2020/03/17 02:47:42[debug]9#9: Not sending request to CloudTrace: no traces or project_id is empty.
```

I've tried to run esp container with --disable_cloud_trace_auto_sampling, didn't help. 
I'd really like to silence these logs, if you have any guesses what could it be, let me know.

Comment: Are you concerned that the logs are being generated (rather than wishing to subsequently filter them per @jkleinne answer)? Are you using `gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime:1` or the v2 beta? I'm using v1, have tried both Swagger and gRPC and am unable to generate the log message even when remove the `cloudtrace.Agent` role from the service account. Please provide more details of your config in your question so that we may help.

Answer (score 0):

> By creating exclusion queries you can control which log entries you exclude (discard).

You can create [exclusion queries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions#exclusion-filters) to discard specific logs. Subsequently, you may also consult the [advanced filters documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries) as well to learn how to create specific queries to exclude logs that are not needed.

> expression = ["NOT"] comparison { ("AND" | "OR") ["NOT"] comparison }

Example:

```
resource.type = "gce_instance" AND
                 severity >= ERROR AND
                 NOT textPayload:robot
```